# Create a concatenated column to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, aggregate-functions, alter-table

I added the column using the alter table function, but I am now trying to use the 'update' and 'set' syntax to successfully update the table and translate the data over in the desired format

I'm basically trying to translate this into a format I can use to update the table:

```
select record_no, string_agg(final_ip_description, ' | ') as Concatenated_IP 
from [dm_na_fin_da].[updated_ip_dataset]
group by record_no
```

Example of desired output (by record_no):

```
record_no   Concatenated_IP
--------------------------------------------------
382102878   Transportation | Energy | Construction
```

When I try to use the below, I get the following error:

```
alter table [dm_na_fin_da].[ip_tiebreaker_ref_table] 
    add Concatenated_IP varchar(100);

update [dm_na_fin_da].[ip_tiebreaker_ref_table] 
set Concatenated_IP = (select string_agg(final_ip_description, ' | ') 
                       from [dm_na_fin_da].[updated_ip_dataset] 
                       group by record_no)
```

**Error**

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Is there a way for me to update this newly formed table column so it displays as shown above?

Comment: You have to correlate your sub-query with the row you want to update, and then you won't need the `group by`.

Comment: Please provide your sample data and desired results as two separate tables. Your query references two different tables, which is not consistent with the scenario of adding/updating a column to an existing column.

Comment: I would rethink this approach and recommend implementing a *view* as suggested in the answer below - by permanently storing aggregated data you are creating the possibility of inconsitency and data corruption, since it's now possibly to update either the column or the source data separately then neither can be considered factual; a trigger could keep things in sync but a view would be the better option.

Comment: This is a SQL Anti-Pattern. Don't denormalise many to many relationships, and certainly don't store multiple values as delimited strings. It may seem like a convenience, but it's a false economy that Will come back and bite you.

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming* that you want to update the new column with the list of descriptions of all IPs of each `record_no`, then, starting from your existing query, you would need to *correlate* the subquery to the outer query (and drop the `having` clause):

```
update r
set concatenated_ip = (
    select string_agg(final_ip_description, ' | ') 
        within group (order by final_ip_description)
    from ip_tiebreaker_ref_table r1 
    where r1.record_no = r.record_no  -- correlation
)
from ip_tiebreaker_ref_table r
```

Note that this assigns the same value to all rows that have the same `record_no` (`within group` is there to make the sort predictable) - which one might consider data duplication - and it is hard to maintain such information up to date when the data changes later on.

Another approach would be to use a view, which gives you an always up-to-date perspective at your data for 0 maintenance costs:

```
create view v_ip_tiebreaker_ref_table as
select r.*, r1.*
from ip_tiebreaker_ref_table r
cross apply (
    select string_agg(final_ip_description, ' | ') 
        within group (order by final_ip_description) as concatenated_ip
    from ip_tiebreaker_ref_table r1 
    where r1.record_no = r.record_no  -- correlation
) r1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that your subquery is not correctly linked to the single records you're trying to update, as long as your subqueries returns multiple rows.

In order to fix this problem, you can try using the `FROM... WHERE` clauses featured in SQL Server `UPDATE` statements.

```
UPDATE [dm_na_fin_da].[ip_tiebreaker_ref_table] 
SET Concatenated_IP = cte.descr
FROM (SELECT record_no, STRING_AGG(final_ip_description, ' | ') AS descr
      FROM [dm_na_fin_da].[updated_ip_dataset] 
      GROUP BY record_no) cte
WHERE [dm_na_fin_da].[ip_tiebreaker_ref_table].record_no = cte.record_no
```

Comment: Does that actually work without referencing the table being updated in the from clause? I always thought you had to join the table being updated with any other tables/sub-queries.

Comment: Looks like this is viable in SQL Server. I've double-checked just in case with a tiny [sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/l6DSaIOT).

Comment: Yes it does, but it's rater unexpected to do so, and better to be explicit with your joins @DaleK

Comment: The reference is present, it's located in the outer `WHERE` clause. I've seen this syntax in PostgreSQL and expected to be working in SQL Server too, that's it.

Comment: Charlie face What's wrong with `UPDATE x SET foo=bar FROM y WHERE x.key = y.key`?

Comment: @MatBailie Becuase it's unexpected to have a cross-join like that. If you forget the `where` you get a cross-join of all rows, whereas if you use explicit `join...on` syntax and leave off the condition then you get a syntax error. it's also more obvious what's going on. Same reason we don't use comma-join syntax. My joined updates always go `update alias1 set ... from table1 alias1 join table2 alias2...`

Answer (score 0):

You can update using `INNER JOIN` as follows :

```
UPDATE [ip_tiebreaker_ref_table]
SET Concatenated_IP = s.Concatenated_IP
FROM [ip_tiebreaker_ref_table] it
INNER JOIN (
  select uid.record_no, string_agg(final_ip_description, ' | ') as Concatenated_IP
  from [updated_ip_dataset] uid
  group by uid.record_no
) as s on it.record_no = s.record_no
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ysWysBKn)